# Draggable and extensible containment

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

i'm trying to the authorize to drag out an object only on the right or bottom side of his containment and cannot do it properly whitout stop dragging the element.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  #parent { height: 500px; width: 500px; border: 1px black solid; }
  #images { height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color:orange; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="images"></div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#images").draggable({
        containment: $("#parent"),
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            var helper = ui.helper, pos = ui.position;
            if(pos.left + parseInt(helper.outerWidth(), 10) == parseInt($("#parent").css("width"), 10)) {
                $("#parent").animate({width: "+=100"});
            }
            if(pos.top + parseInt(helper.outerHeight(), 10) == parseInt($("#parent").css("height"), 10)) {
                $("#parent").animate({height: "+=100"});
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Have you an idea how about refreshing the containment size in order to continue dragging on the right or bottom side ?

Thanks !

Comment: Could you award the bounty, if you're happy with my solution? If nobody else votes for my answer, the 50 points will just evaporate into the ether. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple solution (see [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ek8Fc/5/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  #parent { height: 300px; width: 300px; border: 1px black solid; position: relative; left: 0; }
  #images { height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color:orange; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="parent">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="images"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var
        $document = $(document),
        $parent = $("#parent"),
        $container = $(".container", $parent),
        offset = $container.offset(),
        scrollbarSafety = 15; // use this to avoid dragging outside of window, thus creating scrollbars and wreaking all kinds of havoc on draggables containment checks

    $container
        .width($document.width() - offset.left - scrollbarSafety)
        .height($document.height() - offset.top - scrollbarSafety);

    $("#images")
            .draggable(
            {
                containment: $container,
                drag:
                    function(event, ui)
                    {
                        var
                            $draggee = $(this),
                            draggeePosition = $draggee.position(),
                            shouldWidth = draggeePosition.left + $draggee.width(),
                            shouldHeight = draggeePosition.top + $draggee.height();
                        if($parent.width() < shouldWidth)
                        {
                            $parent.width(shouldWidth);
                        }
                        if($parent.height() < shouldHeight)
                        {
                            $parent.height(shouldHeight);
                        }
            }
            }
        );
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```